# Move an entire line with one Locator using Manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate

When I have one `Locator` I can move a line defined by that `Locator` by clicking anywhere on the line. But, if I have two `Locator`s (using `PaneSelector`), I can't move the line by clicking anywhere. I have to click on the point I set with `Locator` or near it. How can I move a line, by clicking anywhere, when I have two `Locator`s? I NEED to use `Manipulate` and `Locator`!

Right now I have a line defined by `pt` which is linked to my controls.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{pt},
  pt = If[ctrl == 1, pt1, pt2];

  Graphics[{
    PointSize@0.04, Point@pt,
    Thick, Dashed, Line[{{-1, pt[[2]]}, {1, pt[[2]]}}]
    }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
  ],
 Control[{{ctrl, 1}, {1, 2}, Setter}],
 PaneSelector[{
   1 -> Control[{{pt1, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}],
   1 -> Control[{{pt2, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]
   }, Dynamic@ctrl]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you have in mind? (Note that this version doesn't exactly use a locator, though.)

```
DynamicModule[
 {y = 0},

 Graphics[{
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic[Line[{{0, y}, {1, y}}]],
    {"MouseDragged" :> (y = MousePosition["Graphics"][[2]])}
    ]
   },
  PlotRange -> 2,
  Axes -> True
  ]
 ]
```